# Connect all of an objects signals to a single slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Been looking around a bit and people seem to have a similar issue but with multiple signals from different sources etc. My situation is that I have a object that signals if it succeded, failed or got canceled. These signals are passed along to another class and are'nt connected to a slot, just a signal. Now I would like to fix so that no matter what signal the object sends (failed, succeded, canceled) a slot will be called that will delete the object. In short, I want a way of connecting every signal of an object to a slot.

Want to do something like this:

```
connect(myObject, allSignals, this, handleObjectDone());

void handleObjectDone() {
    myObject->deleteLater();
}
```

Is there any way of doing this? Or should I just pass two signals everytime it does something, for example `emit readyToBeDeleted()` and `emit succeded()`?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to delete object which emit signal from connected slot ?

Comment: i want to catch any signal from an object to be able to know when to delete it

Comment: can't you use deleteLater() ?

Comment: deleteLater deletes something at the end of the scope. I have to wait until these requests are ready before I can delete them using delete later

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside any qualms about whether connecting all the signals in one object to a single slot in another object is actually a wise thing to do, below is a function that does that, along with a unit test to verify that it works.

If you watch stdout while you run this, you will see it print out all the connections it is making.  When it runs, clicking on the QLineEdit will cause the QLineEdit to emit a signal, which will (of course) cause the QApplication::quit() slot to be called, so the application will exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QMetaMethod>
#include <QMetaObject>

void ConnectAllSignalsToSlot(QObject * sourceObject, QObject * targetObject, const char * slotName)
{
   const QMetaObject * mo = sourceObject->metaObject();
   if (mo)
   {
      int numMethods = mo->methodCount();
      int firstMethod = mo->methodOffset();  // set to 0 instead if you want to connect signals from superclasses too
      for (int i=firstMethod; i<numMethods; i++)
      {
         QMetaMethod mm = mo->method(i);
         if (mm.methodType() == QMetaMethod::Signal)
         {
            QString signalString = QString("2") + mm.signature();
            printf("Connecting up signal [%s] on object %p to slot [%s] on object %p\n", signalString.toUtf8().constData(), sourceObject, slotName, targetObject);  // just so we can see what it's doing
            QObject::connect(sourceObject, signalString.toUtf8().constData(), targetObject, slotName);
         }
      }
   }
   else printf("Error, sourceObject has no QMetaObject????\n");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QWidget * testSource = new QLineEdit;
   testSource->show();

   ConnectAllSignalsToSlot(testSource, &app, SLOT(quit()));

   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: point of curiosity: why must we prepend "2" to the signal signature? (in other words: could you explain the line: `QString signalString = QString("2") + mm.signature();`)

Comment: ah I see. the "2" is to emulate the `# define SIGNAL(a)   "2"#a` macro. https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/34304e31008/src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h#L86

Answer (score 1):

You can connect any number of signals to any number of slots (as well as other signals). It makes perfect sense to connect the signals to two slots for this purpose. The slots are called in the order they are connected. Emitting two signals consecutively is perfectly reasonable as well. Of course readyToBeDeleted() should be emitted after succeeded() so that the object isn't deleted before emitting its result signal.

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, it's that simple.

Comment: from what ive read, the order the slots are called is random. i just want to solve this in a way so that i dont have to connect every signal twice

Comment: @chikuba No, according to the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html), "If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected, when the signal is emitted."

Comment: but I wont connect multiple slots to one signal. im after some way to actaully connect every signal from one object to one specific slot

Comment: @chikuba You can't _automatically_ connect every signal from an object to a given slot. You have to do it manually, one after the other, in the order you want them to be fired. I don't understand what the problem with that is.

Comment: the doc states http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/signalsandslots.html#signals "If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be executed one after the other, in an arbitrary order, when the signal is emitted." they must have changed this just reasntly then :)